# include static-library without -l

Tags: cocoapods

I'm trying to build a podspec for a third party library which I did not developed.

I've correctly defined: source, preserve_paths, resources, and source_files.

this library include a static library (a .a file). I've tried to use vendored_library and library. I've also tried to set 'LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS' using xconfig. I didn't mange to make it work.

I've noticed from the compile log that if I manually include the library it compile with the following params:

```
".. -framework CoreMedia /Users/luca/..path to the lib.../thelib.a -framework ..."
```

and it works. if I use the the pod it would be (depending on the specification) either be

```
 ".. -framework CoreMedia -l/Users/luca/..path to the lib.../thelib.a -framework ..."
```

or

```
 ".. -framework CoreMedia -lthelib.a -framework ..."
```

I literally spent 4 hours trying to solve this problem. can anyone help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the lines which are needed and worked for me perfectly fine. s.ios.vendored_library is what you are missing.

> s.preserve_paths = 'libCocoaLib.a'
>
> s.library = 'CocoaLib'
>
> s.ios.vendored_library = 'libCocoaLib.a'

s.ios.vendored_library will create a Frameworks folder in your Pod which will have the lib

Answer (score 0):

In case of Cocoa Pods i've managed to do it this way:

> s.preserve_paths = 'libYandexMobileMetrica.a'
>
> s.libraries = 'YandexMobileMetrica'

Generaly speaking, to include library in to the project you need to add flag to linker that tells it to link with library(from man ld):

> Options that control libraries
>
> ```
>  -lx         This option tells the linker to search for libx.dylib or
>              libx.a in the library search path.  If string x is of the
>              form y.o, then that file is searched for in the same places,
>              but without prepending `lib' or appending `.a' or `.dylib' to
>              the filename.
> ```

And then you need to add path to your library to library search path for the linker, again from linker manual:

> ```
>  -Ldir 
>              Add dir to the list of directories in which to search for
>              libraries.  Directories specified with -L are searched in the
>              order they appear on the command line and before the default
>              search path. In Xcode4 and later, there can be a space
>              between the -L and directory.
> ```

Comment: The second part about needing to add the search path (-Ldir) isn't really correct; you can just pass a full path to -l if you want.  -L is an occasional convenience, not a requirement.